# Are spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and Liquibase incompatible?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

I tried to setup a new Spring Boot 2.4.3 project and I want to include Liquibase as well as Spring Data JPA.
To achieve this I use the following dependencies in my POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    or...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
        <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...respectively and 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

with

```
    <kotlin.version>1.4.31</kotlin.version>
    <liquibase.version>4.3.1</liquibase.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.4.29.Final</hibernate.version>
```

Yet, in the beginning, I don't have any DB setup so far and in `application.yaml` you can find:

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog.yml
```

wherbey `db.changelog.yml` is empty.

A Maven install using the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency results in:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Empty file classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog.yml
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Empty file classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog.yml
```

while when commenting out this dependency the build succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the empty `db.changelog.yml` file must contain at least:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeset:
```

although on https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/changelog.html an example is given that an empty `changelog.yaml` file needs to look like:

```
databaseChangeLog:
```

, but this results in a BeanCreationException:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Could not find databaseChangeLog node
```